# Is there a way to insert these flags from this list without the ul .. li?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the list of flags from this url as they're ideal for my purposes.

https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite

The only problem is that in the example, the way to insert the flags is with something like this :

```
<ul class="f32">
<li class="flag ar">Argentina</li>
</ul>
```

The line from the CSS for Argentina looks like this :

```
.f32 .ar{background-position:0 -992px;}
```

The problem is, I want to add these flags into a table and I want them to use as little space as possible. Inside this list, they have big borders and make a mess of my table. I've tried to add them with :

```
echo "<td class = 'f32 flag ar'></td>";
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a way I could just add a flag into my td without having to alter the CSS (it's stored on the Github server and appears to be updated).

Comment: Why not do it like this?`echo "<td><span class = 'f32 flag _ar'></span></td>";`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: The other answer has been deleted but I should add, the suggested method does work fine (using ul/li). I just want to do it without adding them into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `div`s.  Just replace `ul` and `li` tags with `div`s and us the same class names.

I would suggest use `div` tables rather than the old fashioned(`table, tr, ..`) ones.

So all you have to do is replace all `li` & `ul` with `div`. Then style the div to `padding:0px; margin:0px auto;`

The snippet below shows an example :

```css
.f16 .flag{display:inline-block;height:16px;width:16px;vertical-align:text-top;line-height:16px;background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/master/images/flags16.png) no-repeat;}

.f16 .ad{background-position:0 -352px;}
.f16 .ae{background-position:0 -368px;}
.f16 .af{background-position:0 -384px;}
.f16 .ag{background-position:0 -400px;}
.f16 .ai{background-position:0 -416px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Country List</title>
 
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
 ul { font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 ul.f16 { max-width: 320px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; }
 ul.f32 { display: inline-block; }
 .f16 .flag, .f32 .flag { width: auto; clear: right; }
 .f16 .flag { padding-left: 24px; }
 .f32 .flag { padding-left: 44px; }
 .f16 abbr, .f16 i { display: inline-block; width: 24px; }
 .f32 abbr, .f32 i { display: inline-block; width: 32px; line-height: 32px; vertical-align: bottom; }
 .f16 i { margin-left: -48px; margin-right: 24px; color: silver; }
 .f32 i { margin-left: -76px; margin-right: 44px; color: silver; }
 .flag.deprecated { color: silver; }
 .flag.island { color: navy; }
</style>

<div class="f16">
<abbr>  </abbr><li class="flag ac island"><i>AC</i>Ascension Island</li><br/>
<abbr>AD</abbr><div class="flag ad">Andorra(in div)</div><br/>
<abbr>AE</abbr><div class="flag ae">United Arab Emirates(in div)</div><br/>
<abbr>AF</abbr><div class="flag af">Afghanistan(in div)</div><br/>
<abbr>AG</abbr><li class="flag ag">Antigua and Barbuda</li><br/>
<abbr>AI</abbr><li class="flag ai">Anguilla</li><br/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I just put the 'f32' in the td and then the flag in a div. Only slight problem I'm having now is that even with zero padding, it still seems to retain a few pixels above and below which still expands my table a bit. But that's probably a table issue. The solution works.

Comment: Good to know it helped. Try to use `div` tables, they are better than the old `<table>`.

Comment: I know tables are recommended against now, but this is an actual table with about 18 rows and 7 columns. I think table is best for that? Just need to remove a few pixels around the edges of the cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags32.css" />

<table>
    <tr><td class="f32"><i class="flag ar"></i></td></tr>
</table>
```

Also you can do:

```
<table class="f32">
    <tr><td class="flag br"></td></tr>
</table>
```